# How to build a summary table of glm's parameters and AICcWt

Tags: r, data-manipulation, glm

I have a dataset that I am using to build generalised linear models. The response variable is binary (absence/presence) and the explanatory variables are categorical.

**CODE**

```
library(tidyverse)
library(AICcmodavg)

# Data
set.seed(123)
t <- tibble(ID = 1:100,
            A = as.factor(sample(c(0, 1), 100, T)),
            B = as.factor(sample(c("black", "white"), 100, T)),
            C = as.factor(sample(c("pos", "neg", "either"), 100, T)))

# Candidate set of models - Binomial family because response variable
# is binary (0 for absent & 1 for present)
# Global model is A ~ B_black + C_either
m1 <- glm(A ~ 1, binomial, t)
m2 <- glm(A ~ B, binomial, t)
m3 <- glm(A ~ C, binomial, t)
m4 <- glm(A ~ B + C, binomial, t)

# List with all models
ms <- list(null = m1, m_B = m2, m_C = m3, m_BC = m4)

# Summary table
aic_tbl <- aictab(ms)
```

**PROBLEM**

I want to build a table like the one below that summarises the coefficients, standard errors, and Akaike weights of the models within my candidate set.

[image]

**QUESTION**

Can anyone suggest how to best build this table using my list of models and AIC table?

Comment: try the `MuMIn` package?

Comment: By the way, it is not advisable to use a name such as `t` for an object as it is a built-in R function and effectively overwrites it. If any function is going to call it later, it will try to use your dataframe first, instead of the correct call to transpose.

Comment: `ms` is a built-in function in `lubridate`.Might want to change the name too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to point it out: `broom` gets you half-way to where you want to get by turning the model output into a dataframe, which you can then reshape.

```
library(broom)
bind_rows(lapply(ms, tidy), .id="key")
    key        term             estimate std.error            statistic p.value
1  null (Intercept) -0.12014431182649532     0.200 -0.59963969517107030   0.549
2   m_B (Intercept)  0.00000000000000123     0.283  0.00000000000000433   1.000
3   m_B      Bwhite -0.24116205496397874     0.401 -0.60071814968372905   0.548
4   m_C (Intercept) -0.47957308026188367     0.353 -1.35892869678271544   0.174
5   m_C        Cneg  0.80499548069651150     0.507  1.58784953814722285   0.112
6   m_C        Cpos  0.30772282333522433     0.490  0.62856402205887851   0.530
7  m_BC (Intercept) -0.36339654526926718     0.399 -0.90984856337213305   0.363
8  m_BC      Bwhite -0.25083209866475475     0.408 -0.61515191157571303   0.538
9  m_BC        Cneg  0.81144822536950656     0.508  1.59682131202527056   0.110
10 m_BC        Cpos  0.32706970242195277     0.492  0.66527127770403538   0.506
```

And if you must insist of the layout of your table, I came up with the following (arguably clumsy) way of rearranging everything:

```
out <- bind_rows(lapply(ms, tidy), .id="mod")

t1 <- out %>% select(mod, term, estimate) %>% spread(term, estimate) %>% base::t
t2 <- out %>% select(mod, term, std.error) %>% spread(term, std.error) %>% base::t
rownames(t2) <- paste0(rownames(t2), "_std_e")
tmp <- rbind(t1, t2[-1,])
new_t <- as.data.frame(tmp[-1,])
colnames(new_t) <- tmp[1,]
new_t
```

Alternatively, you may want to familiarise yourself with packages that are meant to display model output for publication, e.g. `texreg` or `stargazer` come to mind:

```
library(texreg)
screenreg(ms)

==================================================
                null     m_B      m_C      m_BC   
--------------------------------------------------
(Intercept)      -0.12     0.00    -0.48    -0.36 
                 (0.20)   (0.28)   (0.35)   (0.40)
Bwhite                    -0.24             -0.25 
                          (0.40)            (0.41)
Cneg                                0.80     0.81 
                                   (0.51)   (0.51)
Cpos                                0.31     0.33 
                                   (0.49)   (0.49)
--------------------------------------------------
AIC             140.27   141.91   141.66   143.28 
BIC             142.87   147.12   149.48   153.70 
Log Likelihood  -69.13   -68.95   -67.83   -67.64 
Deviance        138.27   137.91   135.66   135.28 
Num. obs.       100      100      100      100    
==================================================
*** p < 0.001, ** p < 0.01, * p < 0.05
```

Comment: Thanks @coffeinjunky for the two different ways of doing what I wanted. These packages for model output display are very handy